# Mllib decision tree algorithm always gives nearly 100 percent accuracy

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning

I am using Apache Spark's Mllib for twitter sentiment analysis . The decision tree algorithm of MLlib always gives me accuracy between 98 - 100 percent , even if I train and test it on different types of data (.i.e. Tweets obtained from different twitter search queries ). In machine learning it is usually said tat , the model suffers from over fitting if it gives 100 percent accuracy . Is it the same in my case ? I am new to machine learning . Pls do help me out in clarifying my doubt  . Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you testing performance on data the algorithm has been trained on or data it has been blind to?

Comment: I am taking a dataset. Dividing it into 70:30 ...using 70 per for training and 30 per for testing

Comment: Highly probable you have a [label leakage](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/Leakage) in some of the features (feature has 100% correlation with label). E.g. if you have a data like this:

_Feature_  _Label_ 
1.0         Positive
0.0         Negative

Then model can always predict correct label by checking the value of the feature.

Comment: So if the features have 100 % correlation with labels .. Is it something to worry about ? I have tested it on other datasets as well. Yet it gives nearly 100 % accuracy

Comment: It really it depends on how you define your prediction criteria too. If you say the sentiment is "happy" if it contains the word "happy" and "sad" otherwise of course you will easily get 100%.

Comment: I'd suggest to draw a distribution of the labels. In some cases it might be the answer. Let's say you have 1000 samples and 800 labels are 0. In this case   you can just return 0 without any ML algorithm at all with 80% accuracy! 
Spark's random forest in ml package (not mllib) does provide most important features. It makes sense to look at what it returns as it might help with features-label correlation.

Comment: Ok..thanks a lot for ur help.